# How to add dlls in Bin folder to TFS version control

Tags: asp.net, dll, version-control, tfs

I would like to know how to add the referenced libraries to version control.
Is there a possibility to do this? 
The only thing that is checked in is the *.dll.refresh files.

If it's not possible or not recommended which alternative would you suggest so that referenced libraries do not need to be managed seperately from the source files?

Comment: Are these DLLs that you are building from your code or ones that you do not have code for? The general rule of thumb is that you do not put DLLs of anything that you can build yourself into source control, but third-party DLLs should be stored in source control as DLLs.

Comment: I'm talking about third-party libraries here. For some reason only .refresh files are checked in.

Comment: Never checkin a bin folder, because then these files will be downloaded from TFS and have the ReadOnly flag active and this will break builds. Instead of that it is normal practice to have a specific folder for third party libs, usually called common/lib and it is sometimes placed in the main, branch or release pathes, but preferable outside of them. When you add files to TFS check the excluded tab, because by default .dlls are excluded file types.